# Silver Stripe Front end editing for UserDefinedForms

Tags: silverstripe

I am using Silver Stripe [michelsteege/silverstripe-frontend-editing](https://github.com/michelsteege/silverstripe-frontend-editing) . This module is working awesome for Other pages except User defined forms. Is there any way to make the front end editing work with User defined forms? There is no code which I can paste here, as this is a question about a whole module.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue. In the userdefinedform.php class file there is a function index() which renders data based on certain conditions. I have commented out that function and front end editing is working as normal and all other features are working.

Resolved..